# Can you get contents of webbrowser.get in Python?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

Can I get information about contents of the 'a' variable after using webbrowser.get? I can't get anything more than 'webbrowser.WindowsDefault object at 0x024643B0'. I'd like to know which browser is default and transfer this information to string

```
import webbrowser
a = webbrowser.get('windows-default')
print a
a.open('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: What does `print a.name` return

Comment: webbrowser.WindowsDefault object at 0x024643B0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two step solution:

1. Get the class name of the browser object by running: `type(a).__class__`
2. Create a dictionary where you map a browser ***class name*** to a browser ***type name***.

## Details:

When you run `a = webbrowser.get('windows-default')`, you can get the class name of a by: `browser_class = type(a).__class__`.

Based on [below picture](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get), you can code the method highlighted in *2* as follows:

```
def which_browser(browser_class):
   return{
       'Mozilla': 'firefox',
       'Chrome' : 'google-chrome'           
   }.get(browser_class,'firefox')
```

This method returns the browser type name depending on the browser class name you get in `browser_class` above. Note that I set the method to return, by default  *mozilla* but that is not necessarily for a simple test. I mean, you can simply run:

```
def which_browser(browser_class):
   return{
       'Mozilla': 'firefox',
       'Chrome' : 'google-chrome'           
   }
```

You can then call `which_browser()` method to get the browser type name:

```
browser_name = which_browser(browser_class)
```

browser_name is of type `str` as you want it.

You may need this information linked to above:

[image]

## Full program:

I tested the following code according to what I have on my Linux machine where I have installed only 2 browsers:

```
import webbrowser

a = webbrowser.get('windows-default')
   
def which_browser(b):
   return{
       'Mozilla': 'firefox',
       'Chrome' : 'google-chrome'           
   }.get(b,'firefox')

print which_browser(type(a).__class__)
```

After running the program, I get this output: `firefox`.

Comment: It doesn't work it just returns dictionary and I might be wrong but it looks like you give answer already in the program instead of asking for it.

Comment: What does not work?  And no,  I'm not injecting an answer to the program in advance. The fact you said the  program  returns a dictionary means you did not even try to run it, so good luck.